# How to create a custom element that contains special characters in its name?

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, custom-element, createelement

I have a custom HTML element that was registered in an external library with a name containing special Unicode characters. I would like to dynamically create an element of that kind, so I tried to use `document.createElement`, but doing so results in a runtime error in Chrome and Firefox because, apparently, the name of the element is not valid. Only Safari allows creating the element in this way.

Here is a simplified example:

```js
// External code
class TestElement extends HTMLElement
{ }
customElements.define("emotion-", TestElement); // OK
console.log("custom element registered");

// My code
document.createElement("emotion-"); // Error in Chrome and Firefox
console.log("custom element created");
```

Note that the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-core-concepts:valid-custom-element-name-2) itself cites `emotion-` as an example of a valid custom element name.

How can I create such a custom element in JavaScript?

Comment: I do not recognize in your code the normal way of using custom-elements. if that helps, i recently posted a response using custom-elements -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60573934/create-options-with-constructor-javascript/60574214#60574214

Answer (score 1):

You can use `innerHTML` instead `document.createElement` to create your element in DOM

```js
// External code
class TestElement extends HTMLElement
{ }
customElements.define("emotion-", TestElement); // OK
console.log("custom element registered");

// My code
box.innerHTML = "<emotion- class='el'></emotion->"
console.log("custom element created");
```

```css
.el { border: 1px solid red }
```

```html
<div id=box></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Or try to use this solution:

```
function emojiUnicode (emoji) {
    var comp;
    if (emoji.length === 1) {
        comp = emoji.charCodeAt(0);
    }
    comp = (
        (emoji.charCodeAt(0) - 0xD800) * 0x400
      + (emoji.charCodeAt(1) - 0xDC00) + 0x10000
    );
    if (comp < 0) {
        comp = emoji.charCodeAt(0);
    }
    return comp.toString("16");
};
emojiUnicode(""); # result "1f600"
```

Thanks to [How to convert one emoji character to Unicode codepoint number in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419167/how-to-convert-one-emoji-character-to-unicode-codepoint-number-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

To complete other answer you'd rather use `new` with the `class` name to create the custom element:

```
document.body.appendChild( new TestElement )
```

See the example below:

```js
class TestElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    console.log( 'emotion- created' )
    this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } ).innerHTML = 'Hello '
  }
}
customElements.define( 'emotion-', TestElement )

var elem = new TestElement
elem.classList.add( 'el' )
document.body.appendChild( elem )
```

```css
.el { color: red }
```

```html
<emotion-></emotion->
```